# Why does `\pageref` give incorrect page number when a `lstlisting` starts on a new page?

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, pageref

I noticed neither `\pageref` nor `\vpageref` gives me the correct page number when a particular listing starts on a new page and there also is an underfull vbox on the previous page. I think if I fill more text on the previous page just enough so that it is not underfull, I get the correct page number.

In the below MWE, the listing starts on page 5. But `\pageref` and `vpageref` give me page number 4.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright]{book}

\usepackage[nospace]{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\lstnewenvironment{lstSimple}[1][]{
    \lstset{
        #1,
        language     = Java,
        %frame = single,
        %floatplacement=tbp,
        captionpos=t,
        breaklines=true,
        tabsize=8,
        %basicstyle   = \linespread{1}\monospacefnt\addfontfeatures{Color=myParColor, Scale=0.8},
        commentstyle = \color{gray},
        keywordstyle = \color{darkgray}\textbf,
        %stringstyle  = \color{green!70!black},
        %stringstyle  = \color{red},
        columns      = fullflexible,
        numberstyle  = \scriptsize\sffamily\color{gray},
        showstringspaces = false,
        %frame=single,
        %framerule=0pt,
        %framextopmargin=1pt,
        %framexbottommargin=1pt,
        %framexleftmargin=1pt,
        %xleftmargin=4pt,
        framesep=6pt, % if 
        %xleftmargin=3pt, % to move a little to the left if background color is used
        linewidth={\dimexpr \linewidth-3pt},
        aboveskip=4pt,
        belowskip=1pt,
        belowcaptionskip=5pt,        
    }%
}{ }

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext
When I tried vref, even if the referenced item is on the facing/or preceding page, I still get the result with the page number like "Figure 1 on page 23" instead of "Figure 1 on the facing/previous page". If the reference and the referenced item are on the same page, the result seems to work. I get just "Figure 1" without the page number if it's on the same page on which vref is used to refer to it.the result seems to work. I get just "Figure 1" without the page number if it's on the same page on which vref is used to refer to it.

\begin{lstSimple}[caption={[MeetKarel]{MeetKarel}}, label={lst:meet_karel}]
import stanford.karel.Karel;
public class MeetKarel extends Karel { 
        public void run() {
                move();
                move();
                move();
                pickBeeper();
                turnLeft();
                move();
                move();
                turnLeft();
                turnLeft();
                turnLeft();
                move();
                putBeeper();
                move();
        }        
}
\end{lstSimple}
\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext\blindtext

Please see the listing on page \pageref{lst:meet_karel}

Please see the listing on page \vpageref{lst:meet_karel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One wonders why this doesn't pop up more often. listings allows the page to break between the `\refstepcounter` and the caption. Try this after loading listings:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\lst@MakeCaption{\ifx #1t\allowbreak \fi}{}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\lst@MakeCaption{\ifx #1t}{\ifx #1t \allowbreak}{}{\fail}
\makeatletter
```

This moves the `\allowbreak` before the `\refstepcounter`. You should also report this to the maintainer.

Comment: Thanks a lot indeed! As suggested, I've reported this problem to the maintainer as well.